# Deallocating from C++ priority_queue

Tags: c++, memory-management

Is it safe to delete an element in a `std::priority_queue` and pop it afterwards or does the pop try to do anything with the reference other than discarding it?

```
  while(!priority_queue.empty()){
    delete priority_queue.top();
    priority_queue.pop();
  }
```

Comment: What are you storing in your priority queue?

Comment: The priority queue contains std::pairs<int, double>. I'm trying to fix a memory leak in somebody's code.

Comment: How are you even able to call `delete` then if you're not storing pointers?

Comment: @KonradRudolph you were right I will now go to the slaughterhouse.

Comment: My bad currently sick. You're right the std::pairs<int,  double> aren't allocated using new, therefore no pointer only the object itself.

Comment: Easy way to remove memory leak: grep `new` and remove those lines

Comment: @Caleth that way you'll remove Newtons law too

Comment: Just for clarification: So despite my brainfart for the actual problem I had, this is working as intended if the queue stores pointer to objects that need to be deallocated?

Comment: @john if it stores pointers then yes it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After clarification from OP saying that the queue doesn't container any pointers, just objects :

You don't have to call `delete` at all. Just call `pop()` only in your while loop. The container deals with deallocation.

Answer (score 1):

So this page is useful:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/pop/

What it says is that the objects in the queue are destructed.

However if the object doesn't actually have a destructor that deletes its content then you have to delete the content yourself. But that is not OO programming, it is just lazy use of a container.

Note that say a pair of objects that both do have proper destructors will call both destructors correctly.

So in general, no, you shouldn't be deleting the objects explicitly, but is you have lazily written a container of raw pointers, or pairs of pointers, then you will have to, because you wont benefit from destructor calling.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Who knows? And even if they are pointers they don’t necessarily need to be deallocated.

Comment: @KonradRudolph OP calling `delete` on makes it pretty clear.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Nothing in this question is particularly clear.

Comment: @KonradRudolph my vision is 20/20

Comment: @SombreroChicken Might want to see an optician for that, you seem to have developed hindsight.

Comment: @KonradRudolph whatd you expect from a chicken